# Specifying RPM dependency as "one of the following"

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am developing an RPM spec file for an in-house package. The package depends on `libuuid`, which is available as the `libuuid` package on Fedora, but there is no `libuuid` package for CentOS 5 in the standard RPM repositories. We can satisfy the dependency on CentOS with the e2fsprogs-devel development RPM (`e2fsprogs-devel` installs `libuuid` and the associated headers). I would like to specify that our RPM depends on `libuuid`, such that the `libuuid` package is installed on Fedora during installation of our RPM, but `e2fsprogs-devel` is installed during installation on CentOS. Is there a way to specify a dependency as "one of libuuid or e2fsprogs-devel, in that order" in an RPM spec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Use the [Dist Tag](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag) to distinguish between Fedora and one of its derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

You may directly specify files as a requirement but this is ugly. Also don't use %dist for distinguishing.

You should just rely on the build process. If one specific file is located in different packages depending on the distro then you should just (re-) build the package on every distro you wish to support (AutoReq/AutoReqProv must not be disabled).